# Use elrte Editor in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, rich-text-editor, elrte

how can I use elrte Editor inside asp.net website?(any example)

Answer (score 3):

[Elrte Editor](http://elrte.org/) is pure javascript solution (more clear jQuery), so for accessing any of it features you have to use some javascript in your asp.net web-site.

First of all you should add some required folder with all it insertions to you project. You can find it inside installation package - `elrte-1.2.zip`. You have to copy to your project next folders: css, js, images with all subfolders and it content.

Secondly add some reference into your asp page like here:

```
    <!-- jQuery and jQuery UI -->
        <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

        <!-- elRTE -->
        <script src="js/elrte.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elrte.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

        <!-- elRTE translation messages -->
        <script src="js/i18n/elrte.ru.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $().ready(function () {
                var opts = {
                    cssClass: 'el-rte',
                    // lang     : 'ru',
                    height: 450,
                    toolbar: 'complete',
                    cssfiles: ['css/elrte-inner.css']
                }
                $('#editor').elrte(opts);
            })

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { padding:20px;}
    </style>
```

For accessing content of this editor we can use some javascript api that was prepared to us by developers of this editor. So, lets see it [here](http://elrte.org/redmine/projects/elrte/wiki/JavaScript_API_EN) and we will find out that for getting editor content, for example, we can use next expression:

```
var content = $('selector').elrte('val');
```

So, lets add some page and editor interoperability into our page. 
Add some button and textbox to your page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server"  OnClientClick= "ViewText();" Text="View text" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server">test</asp:TextBox>
```

and add next javascript, also:

```
function ViewText() {
            var content = $('#editor').elrte('val');
            alert(content);
            var MyLabel = $('#txtText');
            MyLabel[0].value = content; 
        }
```

After implementing this functionality you can get editor's content as well using javascript alert function and setting your textbox value, which can be accessed in your server code, actually.

Full asp.net page code in my case was:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>elRTE</title>

    <!-- jQuery and jQuery UI -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

    <!-- elRTE -->
    <script src="js/elrte.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elrte.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

    <!-- elRTE translation messages -->
    <script src="js/i18n/elrte.ru.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $().ready(function () {
            var opts = {
                cssClass: 'el-rte',
                // lang     : 'ru',
                height: 450,
                toolbar: 'complete',
                cssfiles: ['css/elrte-inner.css']
            }
            $('#editor').elrte(opts);
        })

        function ViewText() {
            var content = $('#editor').elrte('val');
            alert(content);
            var MyLabel = $('#txtText');
            MyLabel[0].value = content; 
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { padding:20px;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="editor" runat="server">

    </div>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server"  OnClientClick= "ViewText();" Text="View text" />

    <br />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server">test</asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```